# Sas Macros to get schedule the program to run bi-weekly

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, datastep

I have a proc sql code that needs to run twice each month- 1st and the 16th.
There is a where clause in the proc sql.
When the report runs on say January 1st 2022, the where clause filters records that lie between 16December 2021 to 31st December 2021.
And when the report runs on 16th January 2022, the where clause filters records that lie between 01 January 2022 to 15 January 2022.

I have been manually updating these filters everytime I run it but now I need to automate it. There should only be one schedule, which checks for the report run date and accordingly sets the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

To automate date selection, add the following code to your macro. This will create two start/end-date macro variables that hold dates depending on the current day of month.

```
data _null_;

    /* Beginning, end, 15th, and 16th days of this month and last month */
    this_month_b  = intnx('month', today(),  0, 'B');
    last_month_e  = intnx('month', today(), -1, 'E');
    this_month_15 = mdy(month(this_month_b), 15, year(this_month_b) );
    last_month_16 = mdy(month(last_month_e), 16, year(last_month_e) );

    /* Assign start/end dates to macro variables based on the current day of month */
    if(day(today() ) < 16) then do;
        call symputx('start_date', put(last_month_16, date9.) );
        call symputx('end_date',   put(last_month_e,  date9.) );
    end;
        else do;
            call symputx('start_date', put(this_month_b,  date9.) );
            call symputx('end_date',   put(this_month_15, date9.) );        
        end;
run;
```

For example, running it today on Jan 3rd:

```
%put &start_date;
%put &end_date;

16DEC2021
31DEC2021
```

Add these macro variables to your SQL `where` statement.

```
where date BETWEEN "&start_date"d AND "&end_date"d
```

As for scheduling, there are numerous ways you can schedule SAS processes, whether it's through cron, Viya Jobs or another schedule manager. There are a lot of papers out there on how to schedule SAS jobs in batch. How you do that is up to you, but the above code will handle dynamically selecting data when it runs.

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfect. Thankyou so much :)